# WPF Scrollview Panning deceleration

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, scrollview, panning

So official documentation does not state any "default" values on this topic. I have tried with several values like 0.01, 0.1, 1 and I can't seem to get the effect where the ScrollView keeps scrolling after an user lifts a finger.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,210,0,66" x:Name="AboutUsScrollViewer" PanningMode="VerticalOnly" PanningDeceleration="1" PanningRatio="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image x:Name="AboutUsMainImage" Source="Resources\o nama.png"></Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I'm not sure if these are actually device independent units, if so, how do I find the value where I can see the desired effect?

Note: the image is tall enough so there is clearly a lot of room for scrolling, this is not an issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried larger values like 10 or 100?

Comment: Actually yes, I just didn't mention that. To my disappointment nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PanningDeceleration="0.001"
```

That extra zero makes the difference. That should work for you. Start with zero and it should flick without stopping (PanningDeceleration="0"). But with 0.001 it will flick and eventually stop on its own. Play with those numbers and you should get the effect you desire. Wish the Microsoft docs was a bit more informational on the property value it takes. But here is the DOC: [PanningDeceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningdeceleration?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#applies-to)